# Rsyslog regex, include all after first "_"

Tags: regex, rsyslog

I need regex file name of docker service:
docker_service_name

and rename it to contain everything after first "_" to become:
service_name

This now work with rsyslog ERE:

```
    %programname:R,ERE,1,FIELD:_\K[\s\S]*$--end%
```

I tried:

```
    [^docker_]([\s\S]*$)
```

but that also dont work.
Is there any method to exclude "docker_" from my service name?

Example of rsyslog template:

```
$template DOCKER_LOGS,"/var/log/docker/%programname:R,ERE,1,FIELD:[^docker_]([\s\S]*$)--end%/%programname:R,ERE,1,FIELD:[^docker_]([\s\S]*$)--end%.log"

if $syslogtag contains 'docker' then ?DOCKER_LOGS
& stop
```

Comment: Can you add a MCVE?

Comment: Hi JJJ, i added example of rsyslog template.

Comment: Why are you putting `^docker_` inside `[]`?

Comment: I tried exclude it from the match

Comment: But `[]` is to hold a set of characters, like `[a-z]` means match a single character from a to z. Remove these brackets.

Comment: If I use ^docker_([\s\S]*$) or ^docker_(\s\S*$) file name is still docker_service_name

Comment: Guys thanks for help. I get it work by use: _(\S*$) and match group 1